# Setting up a local SVN server that proxies a remote SVN server?

Tags: svn

I've started a new job, and the code for my project is in an SVN server located in a different building managed by another department. Consequently it's an administrative nightmare to modify the SVN server in any way.

I want to add some commit hooks to the remote SVN server so that commits generate diff emails and notify the continuous integration server. I can't do this myself, and it will take a long time for the remote server's administrators to do this.

I'm wondering if I can set up a local SVN server that proxies the remote SVN server. The local SVN server will forward all requests to the remote SVN server, and report back any responses from the remote SVN server (using the credentials of the person making the initial SVN request). On the local SVN server I want to add the post-commit hooks mentioned above.

I don't know enough about SVN servers. Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svnsync` but IIRC it is mostly useful for a one-way mirror of a repository. For committing, you would still need to commit to the main server.

If you can get the admins of the master server to install a commit hook, their server could "ping" your server to resync. But that also is mostly useful for getting a "live mirror".

Then there are a number of tools like `svk` that allow you to locally commit, and then push your changes upstream when desired.

There also is `tailor`, which can even sychronize different repositories. But I'm not sure about how well it works when you have multiple writable copies. I tried it, but found `svnsync` to be much more effective for my use.

Either way, your question should maybe be on superuser.SE instead of here.